# Rest API - SOQL Query : Want to get Only Current user's Record

Tags: soql, rest-api, query, .net

**Rest API - SOQL Query :** 
When I Query i am able to get all user's record instead of mine only. Is there any way to filter for get records of current user only.

Comment: did you try filtering out the records using "createdBy"?

Comment: I do not know how to get User ID for filtering. I have tried like this : "SELECT Id FROM User Where Id=CreatedById". But its not working.

Comment: can you please elaborate your example? Are you querying on standard/custom object? Do you need to filter the records by the current logged in user id or by some specific user?

Comment: Query : SELECT Id, IsPrivate, Name, OwnerId, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LeadSource, Type FROM Opportunity. When I Query I get Thousands of record. And that records is not mine. I want only My records.

Comment: The problem is that using rest api we can get only 2000 records at time. In 2000 records only 5 records is mine.

Comment: And this rest api soql is invoked from a VF page or from some external application? I am asking this coz from wherever you are invoking this, you first need to get your user id. Getting the current user id is easier in apex, the approach would really depend from where your api is being invoked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23099/discussion-between-fenil-suthar-and-rajiv-bhatt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While doing authentication with salesforce, will return response as per bellow :

```
{"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D28000000HpKw***/00528000000HsA7***","issued_at":"1429777622492","scope":"api","instance_url":"https://ap2.salesforce.com","token_type":"Bearer","signature":"HHORb4H9yZ6+fjYtn6OLBbeRvof9n4TuaXpYVh2qgck=","access_token":"00D28000000HpKw!AQcAQA8emoHQ8upI19zT_Yr4ctNAyE5lxc8yv6uFZbnszyNJOiF1ONC1ZsTcvoOtFduxxSEEquJdAoyq2E1Sn5mugFWqqUrJ"}
```

Response contains "Userid" at the end of "id" string (starts with 005).

Userid : "00528000000HsA7***"
Use that UserID in filter as per bellow :

```
/services/data/v29.0/query?q=SELECT+Name+from+Opportunity+where+OwnerId=+'00528000000HsA7***'
```

Comment: excellent! and where did you get this info from?!

Comment: Obviously from you..! @RajivBhatt

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user record then for standard fields no soql query required.
you can directly use UserInfo class and its appropriate methods.

UserInfo Methods: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex230/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm

If you want other object records which are created by current user then try this:

Id currentUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();

List oppList = [SELECT Id, IsPrivate, Name, OwnerId, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LeadSource, Type FROM Opportunity where createdById=:currentUserId ];

Comment: Fields,Object Name And Filter Query is dynamically generated from .net program as per user's selection and user-wise its different-different. So, i think SOQL query is most convenient way..

Answer (score 0):

CreateBy wont help. Try this instead.
List testList = [SELECT Id, IsPrivate, Name, OwnerId, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LeadSource, Type FROM Opportunity where createdById=:**currentUserId** ];

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT AccountId
 From User
 WHERE username=:UserInfo.getUsername())
```

Select accountId then check if these records were created by current user in apropriate WHERE clause in your query (you can nest it)

Comment: SOQL query is not support  "UserInfo.getUsername()". Only Apex class/code support like this. I want to do exactly like this in SOQL query. I am fetching record throw Rest API Query call from .net web application.